# send keys in WndProc method in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I override WndProc method in windows form and use SendKeys.

I wanna send "CTRL + N" when the bool value if true and wanna send just "n" when bool value is false.

My problem is here when i send "n" send unlimited "n".

Is the any way to fix this ?

```
   public ShiledMaker()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        RegisterHotKey(Handle, (int)Keys.N, 0, (int)Keys.N);
   }


  protected override void WndProc(ref Message xMessage)
  {
        base.WndProc(ref xMessage);

        if (bool value)
             SendKeys.Send("n");
        else
             SendKeys.SendWait("^n");
  }
```

Comment: Why are you calling that from `WndProc` for all messages?

Comment: because i declare much short cut keys like these. i change some shortcut key for myself

Comment: Then you should only call that when you get the message you want, not all messages.

Comment: To handle shortcuts, override `ProcessCmdKey`.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean value is added in your class. If the key is sent I am changing it to true. So that the keypress event is called only once.

```
class MyClass {

   private bool keySent = false;

   protected override void WndProc(ref Message xMessage)
   {
        if (keySent)
            return;

        base.WndProc(ref xMessage);

        if (bool value)
             SendKeys.Send("n");
        else
             SendKeys.SendWait("^n");

        keySent = true;

   }
}
```